# Lookup lists in microservices

Tags: design-patterns, architecture, microservices, lookup, lookup-tables

When developing microservices where each microservice has its own database, the issue of "sharing" lookup data becomes challenging.
So I'm wondering what is the best practice for dealing with this?

1. Create a separate `Lookups Microservice` which exposes the data through a Web API?
2. Save the lookups which are relevant to each microservice in its own database?

If we go with the second option (which is my preferred one), do you think it's a good idea to share the lookups across all microservices through a distributed cache, or should this be restricted through the API of each microservice?

Any other suggestions?

Comment: In one of my designs I have a lookup/metadata service, which gets called when data needed first time. Data then cached in the local app cache and used from there for speed. To keep data fresh, we have Redis sub/pub connectivity. If metadata changes, broadcast goes to all connected services to clear certain local cache. During next usage it is reloaded (new version)

Answer (score 0):

It depends on many factors, on the scale of your current microservice architecture, on the requirements for the quality and speed of the search service, on the timing and cost of implementing this functionality, as well as plans for the future scaling of the system.

For a small or initial system, the option that you suggested as the second option is considered acceptable, in which each microservice provides an api interface for data retrieval.
The advantages of such a solution, I would attribute the ease of understanding and implementation of such an architecture.
But in the future, you will face problems of retrieving and aggregating data from different databases of different services.

For the future development and scaling of the architecture, I would suggest using a search engine for this, for example elasticsearch, which can be filled with data from each database, for example, through the Apache Kafka message broker, using the connector mechanism.
And then you can make a separate search service that will provide data through the api from elasticsearch.
And also in the future, a caching mechanism can easily be built into such an architecture.
The disadvantages include the increased complexity and cost of the overall architecture and system support.
The advantages include the good scalability of such an architecture.

There is a good article on this topic at [this link](https://www.confluent.io/blog/simplest-useful-kafka-connect-data-pipeline-world-thereabouts-part-1/).